# Perform Basic Authentication on WSDL

Tags: web-services, authentication, delphi

I need to interface with a WSDL webserver, this is the first time that I have to use this type of technology, usually I don't deal with web programming.
Having never done this, I did some tests before using some WSDLs available on the net and it worked, but now I find myself completely blocked because the WSDL to which I have to interface needs a "Basic" authentication,
just "User name" and "password".
I have read many posts on the net but none of the things seen have solved the problem.
I am on Delphi Rio 10.3 version, I have seen that there are differences between authentication before and after the Rio version I use.
The part related to the creation of the interfacing unit works without problems, but I cannot use the interface created because I always get an authentication error 401.
The methodology performed is this:

```
 ZWS_TEST02 = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{C6FABE09-74A8-3DE6-906F-B1D33E6F4B09}']
    function  ZWS_TEST02(const I_PAR01: char255): char255; stdcall;
 end;

function GetZWS_TEST02(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): ZWS_TEST02;
const
  defWSDL = '--MY LINK--------?wsdl';
  defSvc  = 'ZWS_TEST02';
  defPrt  = 'BND_TEST02';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
      Addr := defWSDL
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then begin
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  end else begin
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  end;
  
  try
     
      Result := (RIO as ZWS_TEST02);

      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;

      RIO.HTTPWebNode.UseDefaultCredentials:=true;
      RIO.HTTPWebNode.UserName:='User';
      RIO.HTTPWebNode.Password:='Password';

      
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Actually the 401 error comes out when I don't insert the two lines of code that set the user and password, while when I enable these two lines I get an error 12007 "unable to resolve the server name or address"!?

Having read that for older Delphi versions you had to use the OnBeforePost event instead,
I tried to use it on Seattle but without success. In practice, the assigned event was this:

```
procedure TForm1.BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  UserName: string;
  PassWord: string;
  auth:string;
begin

  UserName := 'User';
  Password := 'Password';

  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(UserName + ':' + Password);
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
end;
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong, or how can I fix this authentication problem?

Comment: Did you import the WSDL or are you coding all this from scratch?

Comment: I imported the wsdl via delphi wizard.
The procedure worked perfectly.